# Telegram bot is running, but does not retrieve data from the database

Tags: xampp, mysql-connector, python-3.9, aiogram

> trying to output data from sql to telegram bot. bot is
> running(sending message.answer), but after that nothing happens and
> shows no error. using pycharm and xampp. it  is my first code

```
    import logging
    import mysql.connector
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    
    API_TOKEN = 'token'
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    
    bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database="php"
    )
    
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer("Hi!\nEnter name:")
    # works up to this line
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    async def send_msg(message: types.Message):
        mycursor.execute(
            "SELECT surname, age, year, city, phone FROM list WHERE name ='{}'".format(message.from_user.id))
        # fetching the rows from the cursor object
        result = mycursor.fetchone()
        for x in result:
            await message.answer(x)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: are you able to retrieve any row of data right after the `mycursor = mydb.cursor()` line?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer("Hi!\nEnter name:")
    # works up to this line
    await state.set_state("get_name")
    
    
@dp.message_handler(state="get_name")
async def send_msg(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    mycursor.execute(
        "SELECT name FROM users WHERE name ='{}'".format(message.from_user.id)) # message.text should be here? 
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    for x in result:
        await message.answer(x)
    await state.finish()
```

You could use [**FSM**](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html) to get data from user